# RAM usage wrong when using pointers to class

Tags: c++, object, memory, arduino

I don't understand how the RAM usage is estimated by the compiler. I made the following MCVE.
After compiling (Arduino nano ATMEGA328P, new bootloader), the RAM usage shown by the Arduino compiler is wrong. I compared creating instances of the `DataContainer` struct in two ways, by having an array of pointers and call constructor using `new` (run time, heap? is that the correct name) and by just creating an array of the struct (compile time?).

```
#include <Arduino.h>

struct DataContainer {
    int values[100] = {0}; // init to zeros
    void FillRandom() {
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
            values[k] = random(0, 200);
    }
};

class ExampleClass 
{
public:
    DataContainer *data[20]; // Heap, runtime?
    // DataContainer data[20]; // or compile time

    ExampleClass() {
        for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
            data[k] = new DataContainer(); // not necessary when using: DataContainer data[20]
    }
};

// declare class
ExampleClass EC;

void setup() {
    // call constructor
    EC = ExampleClass();
    EC.data[1]->FillRandom(); // for run time
    // EC.data[1].FillRandom();  // for compile time
}
```

If I compare the RAM usage that the compiler displays, I see the following.

Case 1, using `DataContainer *data[20];`

```
RAM:   [          ]   3.1% (used 63 bytes from 2048 bytes)
Flash: [=         ]   5.8% (used 1782 bytes from 30720 bytes)
```

Case 2, using `DataContainer data[20];`

```
RAM:   [==========]  195.9% (used 4013 bytes from 2048 bytes)
Flash: [          ]   3.9% (used 1194 bytes from 30720 bytes)
```

(I know that this is not gonna fit on the Arduino, just as an example).

Is there a way to still get an estimate of the RAM usage?

Comment: Compilers doesn't really know how much memory you allocate dynamically at run-time, it's requires much more analysis that is typically needed by a compiler. All it can do it to estimate using the information it has, which is that you create an object on the stack, whose size is `20 * 4` bytes. How it counts "RAM" I don't know, but when running your program will use up at least 80 bytes of memory (plus little extra for return address etc.) on the stack. If you create an array of *objects* then that's at least `20 * (100 * 4)`, which is 8000 bytes, at least, on the stack.

Comment: As for the discrepancies, perhaps your Arduino model (which you don't tell us) is using a 16-bit  CPU, where `sizeof` of a pointer as well as for an `int` is 16 bits (2 bytes) each? Then it would make more sense.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use a nano (see update). So if I allocate dynamically at run-time, I will have to calculate myself how much memory the `EC` class will use? To be sure that the program will run, and not break at any point. Is there another disadvantage of using dynamic allocation on Arduino I have to be aware of, or just the RAM usage?

Comment: On small embedded systems, like an Arduino Nano, dynamic memory allocation is almost always going to be to much overhead. Not only do you need the memory for the objects themselves, you also need memory for the *pointers* to the objects, as well as the memory allocator internal house-keeping and meta-data. Since you only have 2KiB of RAM, you have to be very conservative with your variables and objects, and have to base your design from the ground up on this limitation.

Comment: I have considerable experience of writing operating systems for memory-constrained devices, and I strongly suggest that with only 2048 bytes of RAM, you should be programming in C, not C++.

Comment: @TonyK  People are programming successful arduino apps in C++ everyday,

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: Yes. And I strongly suggest that they don't.

Comment: @TonyK They still do, and will.  And the apps, and the libraries work.  Which is the main thing.  Also, C++ is not anymore the RAM hog it used to be.  If C++ helps get things built faster (for once!), nothing will change anybody's mind on the matter.  Most apps never use all of an MCU"s resources, even in C++.

Comment: Anyone using C++ on a device with 2048 bytes of RAM is either tinkering or oblivious to the trouble.  C or assembly -- and static, compile-time data structures -- are the way to go.  Just think of these devices as having ZERO "heap" and design accordingly.  And especially don't use the ridiculous String class.

Comment: Ok in the end I want to use an ESP32 (520 KiB RAM), but I just was testing what the compiler says about RAM usage with different memory allocation methods. Your comments made it perfectly clear what's going on, so thanks. Trying to learn c++ during this project, but I will remember to stick to C with e.g. nano's.

Comment: @rinkert  The Arduino ecosystem is in C++.  So you don''t have much choice in the matter.  Unless you want to go native,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use dynamic allocation on 16 bit MCUs.  Especially not on a nano.  There's just not enough RAM.

Estimating needed RAM space is simple.

1. Calculate the size of your structure.

   struct DataContainer {
       int values[100] = {0}; // init to zeros
       /* ... */
   };

100 x sizeof(int) = 100 x 2 = 200.

2. Calculate the size of your array.

   DataContainer data[20];

20 x 200 = 4000 bytes.

Some notes about your code....

```
// declare class
ExampleClass EC;   //  Good!  On small MCUs, global variables are the thing!
                   //  Note that the constructor HAS BEEN called.

void setup() {
    // call constructor
    EC = ExampleClass();    // ???  Why are you creating a new object???
                            // creating a 4000 bytes object on the stack 
                            // is a sure way to crash your app.  I give it
                            // no more than a couple of microseconds before 
                            // crashing on a nano.

                            // This line of code is not needed, EC is already 
                            // initialized.

                            // Always leave room on the stack, it's needed for 
                            // calling functions and also for interrupts.
    /* ... */
}
```

Explanation:  This line, `EC = ExampleClass();`  creates a temporary object on the stack, then copies it into global variable EC.

The reason why the compiler indicates only 4000 bytes of used memory is because stack space is not included in the count.  Your code needs 4000 bytes of global memory RAM + 4000 bytes for the temporary variable on the stack, and then will need some more just to run.